# PostgresSQL xpath with namespaces

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql, xpath, namespaces

I would like to know how to use the xpath funtion in the following example:

1. The xml is inside a table called SR_DATA, field XMLDATA of type TEXT
2. The following is the structure of the xml document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<modulo modelCodeScheme="DocType" modelCodeSchemeVersion="01" modelCodeValue="TYPE_20a" modelCodeMeaning="SCREENING" group="groupname" type="format" xmlns="http://www.expr.com/2008/FMSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <AAAAA modelCodeScheme="MAM" modelCodeSchemeVersion="1" modelCodeValue="AN_MAM_6" modelCodeMeaning="Family1" tipodato="booleano">
        <![CDATA[false]]>
    </AAAAA>
    <BBBBB modelCodeScheme="MAM" modelCodeSchemeVersion="1" modelCodeValue="AN_MAM_8" modelCodeMeaning="Family2" tipodato="booleano">
        <![CDATA[false]]>
    </BBBBB>
</modulo>
```

3. Let's say I want to read the text about the element named AAAAA, so my query looks like this:

```
SELECT (xpath('/modulo/AAAAA/text()', XMLDATA::xml) AS status
FROM SR_DATA;
```

My query doesn't raise any error but the resultset is empty; I suppose I have to map the NAMESPACES but I need a hint on how to do it.

Comment: For any reasons the `xmlns` is problematic here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e6e8c46176ff4a7fe0c7bb4772baa3fc But I don't know why. The problem is already descibed here https://postgrespro.com/list/thread-id/1967027 but without a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify namespaces in the `xpath` function. The node contains multiple text nodes; you could combine the nodes together using `array_to_string` function:

```sql
SELECT TRIM(BOTH FROM array_to_string(xpath('/x:modulo/x:AAAAA/text()', XMLDATA::xml, ARRAY[
    ARRAY['x', 'http://www.expr.com/2008/FMSchema']
]), ''))
FROM SR_DATA
-- false
```

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=50933f5b0ef1a903fadad0b07bb715be)